# Websites on subdomains

Tags: hosting

I am searching a web host and was told that I "have to" get a VPS for what I want to do and I wanted to double check with you if that is true (and not that I pay for a service that I don't need).

My plan:

1) Create Website 1 on Main Domain = www.example.com which is based on the Joomla CMS

2) Create Website 2 consisting of OpenAtrium (Drupal) on Sub-Domain = start.example.com

3) Create Website 3 consisting of Moodle (Open Source Learning Platform) on Sub-Domain 2 = learning.example.com

Do I really need a VPS or can I go just with shared hosting. Was thinking about squirrelhosting or lcn.

Comment: You don't need a VPS to host multiple sites on a single server and/or domain

Comment: What server are you using? IIS makes it easy to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Many shared hosts will let you do this.  [TotalChoice Hosting](http://www.totalchoicehosting.com/) is the one I would recommend, but there are many others.

Moodle is really fat though and most shared hosts won't be happy about you running it on their servers, since it will slow everything down with its bloated code and slow database queries.  It might be worth a VPS just for that if you plan to use any of its plugins.  If your issue with a VPS is cost, consider one of the lower cost options like [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=047e545d941f).  *(Full Disclosure: that link as my referral code in it, but I'm suggesting them because they are cheap and solid for most small applications.)*  Again with Moodle though, you might need more RAM than 512MB.

Comment: I was told I need a PHP memory limit starting from 512MB. Is it this what you mean with the RAM or is it something different? Also, I might need UK based servers.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If your PHP memory limit is 512MB, you're going to want 1GB of RAM so that there is some for the rest of the system.  If you need a PHP memory limit that high, you won't find that in shared hosting plans.  You need a VPS.  Although do test to see if you actually need a limit that high.